# how to prevent selected special character in text box?

Tags: jquery

how to prevent special character in input box ?

especially i dono want to use this special character (<>!$%^??/{}[])

I already use this sample code.... its working perfect

```
$('input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=textarea]').bind('keypress', function   (e)  {        
        var keyCode = e.which;
        var ret = ((keyCode == 46) ||
                   (keyCode == 35) || 
                   (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 59) || 
                   (keyCode >= 64 && keyCode <= 90) || 
                   (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122));  
        return ret;
});
```

**i want to check the character , when the key is pressed  (<>!$%^??/{}[])**

Comment: you have to use regular expression

Comment: This is your **17th** question, you should be able to correctly mark up code by now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your help,

i have solved the problem using  this way...

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="textarea"]').bind('keypress', function (event) {        
var regex = new RegExp("^[>/[/~/{/}/!/&/$/%/^/(/`/)/+/=/?/<]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
```

have cheers up

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i already used this code, but in my case, arabic language are not accepting the character........

Comment: how to check special character in this way (<>!$%^??/{}[])

Comment: @PrasadRaja so for that before you send any char for validation you need to encode it first.I think that will work for you rest you need to do Google.

Comment: in that case only, i want to check the expression with this special character (<>!$%^??/{}[]).....

Comment: @PrasadRaja i have thought of one solution first split your string in the form of array and try to compare your char with slitted item like  suppose i have("x[] !") first split this string and now check your input char with splitter text if it matches ignore that char

Comment: can you provide with the example

Answer (score -2):

jquery
let your textbox

```
<input type="text" id="DivisionName" />

$('input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=textarea]').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log( e.which );
    if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0){
        var k = e.which;
        var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
            k >= 97 && k <= 122 || // a-z
            k >= 48 && k <= 57; // 0-9

        if (!ok){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/D4dcg/101/)

Comment: `if($('#DivisionName').val().length == 0)`??? Where did you *cut & paste* that code from?

Comment: dude i forget to add textbox . just me correct my code. don't downvote it'

Comment: i already used this code, but in my case, arabic language are not accepting the character........

Comment: how to check special character in this way (<>!$%^??/{}[])

Comment: It is certainly not the only way. Also, you would never reference `$('#DivisionName')` explicitely when you have `$(this)` available instead